# how to solve "can not Create Interpreter error in android while intigrating tflite model"?

Tags: android, keras, tensorflow-lite

I have trained simple ANN using keras with tensorflow backend. ANN includes 3 Dense layers. I have converted keras `.h5` model to `.tflite` using tflite converter. When I am trying to load this model in Interpreter in android it showing following error:

Internal error: can not create interpreter: Didn't find op for builtin opcode 'FULLY_CONNECTED' version '3'.

Answer (score 1):

Change dependencies in `app/build.gradle`:

`implementation "org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly"`